# How to disable anti aliasing in mesa drivers

Tags: amd-graphics, mesa

How to disable anti-aliasing in Mesa drivers I am running Rx 560 in ubuntu 16.04 and I haven't ever used Linux before.

Answer (score 0):

You've put your finger on something crucial.  Just mentioning, when developing videogames all anti-aliasing modes disrupt development when using non-Microsoft solutions.  Most standard game development platforms including Unreal Engine and the like have that covered as well as Monodevelop.

Not disabling anti-aliasing will destroy the render of your product on low level system development kits, if that's what you are doing.  Anti-aliasing should be achieved internally to your organization.

Anyways, the best way to answer your question is to check your specific API documentation.

In Unreal?  I don't know.

Comment: Hi Joel, welcome to AskUbuntu!  I think the OP is asking a specific technical question, whereas your answer is more general and philosophical.  Can you add information like *where* they can find the specific API documentation?  Thanks!

Comment: My general feeling is that APIs are flawed hence a lack of suggested documentation.  Thanks Tudor!